# A "clip" or active webpage on desktop/sidebar with admin access/macro

Tags: windows-7, boot, macros, dashboard, ticket-system

Hopefully I explain this well.  I commonly log into a support system that keeps track of active tickets.  Instead of navigating to the support page, logging in, and posting a query for new tickets, would it be possible for a widget in the sidebar to login and load at startup?  Maybe use a macro to log in?  Any help/solution is appreciated.

The ticket system is EBSuite: On Demand Business Tools I login via the web interface.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it really depends on the API of the ticket system

Comment: if your application has a web interface you can use password management tools like lastpass, or the browser built-in password management, and setting your browsers home page to the tickeing app url, you can put the browser to launch at startup

Comment: gotcha, the system is EBSuite: On Demand Business Tools

Comment: As far as performing the query, should I use a macro?  I suppose I could have the browser login at boot, then the macro to login and execute the query.  Any recommended Macro software then that is free?